# Only 2 ranks may be shown on the rank system

Tags: php, mysql

I'm busy with a table which is showing the VIP points of my users.
But I don't want the people with a higher rank than 3 on this list.
This is the code I'm using now but this is also showing people above the 3rd rank:

```
<?php

$count = 1;

$users_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY vip_points DESC LIMIT 7");
while ($users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_a)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $users['id'] . "' LIMIT 10"));
?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Or how I can fix this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You have to close off that while, for one thing. And use a where clause

Comment: Unless you are saying you want to create a rank / rownum concept, using variables, I think you need to describe it better

Comment: rank is the position of a record in the result or is it an explicit field. it it's the latter you'll want to use `WHERE rank<3`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
GROUP BY `vip_points` having vip_points>3
ORDER BY vip_points DESC LIMIT 7
```

Comment: how would that group by work, in the face of `select *` ?